# JBOSS JBAS011565: Failed to write configuration file

Tags: configuration-files, jboss-eap-6

I'm rolling over from JBOSS 5.2 to JBOSS EAP 6.4.8.  I observed `JBAS011565: Failed to write configuration file` during startup and uncertain as what I need to do with a localhost JBoss EAP 6.4.8 implementation.  Should I ignore this error?  If not, what should I do to address it?

Here is the complete logging of this issue:

```
12:33:35,965 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]   
(Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014781: Step handler 
org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingOperations$CommitOperationStepHandler@18b1625c 
for operation {"operation" => "add","address" => [("subsyst
em" => "logging")],"add-logging-api-dependencies" => undefined} at address    
[("subsystem" => "logging")] failed handling operation rollback -- 
java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS011565: Failed to write configuration file 
C:\IBU\jboss\jboss-eap-6.4.8\standalone\configuration\logging.properties:  
java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS011565: Failed to write configuration file  
C:\IBU\jboss\jboss-eap-6.4.8\standalone\configuration\logging.properties
    at  
org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.ConfigurationPersistence.writeConfiguration(ConfigurationPersistence.java:409) [jboss-as-logging-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingOperations$CommitOperationStepHandler$1.handleResult(LoggingOperations.java:107) [jboss-as-logging-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1151) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1108) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1083) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1028) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.finishStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:822) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:778) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:537) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:338) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:314) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1144) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:416) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:301) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:363) [jboss-as-server-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:338) [jboss-as-server-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:263) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\IBU\jboss\jboss-eap-6.4.8\standalone\configuration\logging.properties (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
    at org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.ConfigurationPersistence.writeConfiguration(ConfigurationPersistence.java:395) [jboss-as-logging-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Sounds like a filesystem user rights problem. The server will try to update/clean the main configuration file (for example: standalone.xml if it is the standalone server) and apparently fails to do so. If you should ignore that is pretty much opinionated; I wouldn't.

Comment: @Gimby JBoss EAP 6.4.8 was pulled from perforce and I then copied the folder to another directory and purged all the read-only files.  I am still receiving the (Access is denied) indication.

Comment: this may mean that you do not have permissions to the file, that the file is currently open in another process which prevents writing to it, or that the file is set to read-only. Check any dependency missing at Application level , caused server startup issues.

Answer (score 0):

i ran the .bat file as administrator and it worked